# How to display image and text in both sides in a loop?

Tags: php, android, mysql

Here is ,y code for selecting images and texts from mysql database through php.And it is displaying in a linearlayou in a scrollview.All i want to do is change the allignment of the display.I tried many ways but its not working properly.Im new in android,anybody please help me.

**JAVA**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class News_and_events extends Fragment {
    private String jsonResult;
     private String url = "http://192.168.2.7/crescentnews/select.php";
     HttpPost httppost;
     StringBuffer buffer;
     HttpResponse response;
     HttpClient httpclient;
     List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
     ProgressDialog dialog = null;
     ImageView img;
      Bitmap bitmap;
      ProgressDialog pDialog;


   // alert dialog manager
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    // Internet detector
    ConnectionDetector cd;

     InputStream is=null;
     String result=null;
        String line=null;
        int code;

    public News_and_events(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_news_and_events, container, false);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(rootView.getContext());

        // Check if Internet present
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            // Internet Connection is not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(getActivity(),
                    "Internet Connection Error",
                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
            // stop executing code by return
            //return.rootView;
            return rootView;
        }

        accessWebService();
        return rootView;
    }

    // Async Task to access the web
     private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 
          List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);


       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
       try {

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
        jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
          response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        }

       catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
      }

       private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
       String rLine = "";
       StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
       BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

       try {
        while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
         answer.append(rLine);
        }
       }
        catch (IOException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
          "Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       return answer;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       display();
      }
     }// end async task

     public void accessWebService() {
      JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
      // passes values for the urls string array
      task.execute(new String[] { url });
     }

     // build hash set for list view
     public void display() {


      try {
       JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
       JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("news_details");
       LinearLayout MainLL= (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.newslayout); 
       //LinearLayout headLN=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.headsection);

       for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
            final String head = jsonChildNode.optString("title");
            final String details = jsonChildNode.optString("text");
            final String date = jsonChildNode.optString("date");
            final String image = jsonChildNode.optString("img");
            //final String time = jsonChildNode.optString("time");
            //img = new ImageView(this.getActivity());
            //new LoadImage().execute("http://192.168.2.7/crescentnews/images/"+image);

            img = new ImageView(this.getActivity());
          //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),image, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            LoadImage ldimg=new LoadImage();
            ldimg.setImage(img);
            ldimg.execute("http://192.168.2.7/crescentnews/images/"+image);


            TextView headln = new TextView(this.getActivity());
            headln.setText(head); // News Headlines
            headln.setTextSize(16);
            headln.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            headln.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            headln.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffcd14"));
          //  headln.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menubg);
            headln.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);
          //  headln.setHeight(50);
            headln.setClickable(true);


            TextView dateln = new TextView(this.getActivity());
            dateln.setText(date); // News Headlines
            dateln.setTextSize(12);
            dateln.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            dateln.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            //dateln.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f20056"));
            dateln.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
            dateln.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 10);
            dateln.setWidth(100);
            dateln.setClickable(true);



            View sep=new View(this.getActivity());
            sep.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#252525"));
            sep.setMinimumHeight(10);

            TextView detailsln = new TextView(this.getActivity());
            detailsln.setText(details); // News Details
            detailsln.setTextSize(12);
            detailsln.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            detailsln.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            detailsln.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

            int width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            int height = 200;
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
           img.setLayoutParams(parms);
           parms.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
           img.setPaddingRelative (15, 15, 15, 15);

            MainLL.addView(headln);
            MainLL.addView(dateln);
         //   MainLL.addView(photo);
            MainLL.addView(img);
            MainLL.addView(detailsln);
            MainLL.addView(sep);

            img.setClickable(true);

           // img.buildDrawingCache();  
           // final Bitmap bmap = img.getDrawingCache();
            headln.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),InnerNewsAndEvents.class);
                    intent.putExtra("head",head.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("details",details.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("date",date.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("image", image);
                    startActivity(intent);       

                }
            });

            dateln.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),InnerNewsAndEvents.class);
                intent.putExtra("head",head.toString());
                intent.putExtra("details",details.toString());
                intent.putExtra("date",date.toString());
                intent.putExtra("image", image);
                startActivity(intent);       
                }
            });

            img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),InnerNewsAndEvents.class);
                intent.putExtra("head",head.toString());
                intent.putExtra("details",details.toString());
                intent.putExtra("date",date.toString());
                intent.putExtra("image", image);
                startActivity(intent);       
                }
            });

            detailsln.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),InnerNewsAndEvents.class);
                    intent.putExtra("head",head.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("details",details.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("date",date.toString());
                    intent.putExtra("image", image);
                    startActivity(intent);       
                    }
                });
       }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
       Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error" + e.toString(),
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
       }

     private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
         ImageView img;
                     @Override
                         protected void onPreExecute() {
                             super.onPreExecute();

                             pDialog.setMessage("Loading Image ....");
                             pDialog.show();


                     }
         public void setImage(ImageView img ){
         this.img=img;
         }

         protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
             try {
                 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(args[0]).openStream());
                 } 
             catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
             return bitmap;
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
              if(image != null){
                  img.setImageBitmap(image);

                  pDialog.dismiss(); 
              }
              pDialog.dismiss(); 
         } 

     }

     public static boolean isInternetReachable()
     {
         try {
             //make a URL to a known source
             URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");

             //open a connection to that source
             HttpURLConnection urlConnect = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

             //trying to retrieve data from the source. If there
             //is no connection, this line will fail
             Object objData = urlConnect.getContent();

         } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return false;
         }
         catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             return false;
         }
         return true;
     }
}
```

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"![enter image description here][1]
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"

         >

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/newslayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#ffffff"

                >     

            </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>



    </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Required display style
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/listview_with_sdcard_screenshot.png

Comment: First of all you need to use Listview to implement such design, then define a single layout for a row in an xml. Refer to this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Answer (score 0):

You try the following link; this is the same as you expect:
http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134

Comment: I tried that ways but its not at all working properly.
CAn anybody alter my code for my requirement please,im new in android thats why.

Answer (score 0):

Your design approach towards layout is wrong. When you need such layouts in design where you have same layout repeating for different data you use **ListView**. You can learn more about ListView here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: You need to follow some tutorial to implement Listview. You also need to implement Adapter for ListView and after you get data from JSON, set that adapter to ListView. There are dozens of Listview examples on web. Some of them are:
http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=9
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html